# How to use Split with TryParse?

Tags: c#

I'd rather not throw an exception if the user enters one or more invalid doubles in a textbox.
This is kind of what I'd like to do but it is wrong of course.

```
double myDouble[];
double.TryParse(textBox1.Text.Split(' '), out myDouble);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

how about...

```
var myDoubleList = new List<double>();
foreach(var doubleString in textBox1.Text.Split(' '))
{
    double myDouble;
    if (double.TryParse(doubleString, out myDouble))
        myDoubleList.Add(myDouble);    
}
```

Answer (score 6):

`TryParse()` is only trying to parse a **single** double value - you cannot use it with arrays. You could try and see if any number is invalid:

```
double myDouble;
bool parseFailed = textBox1.Text.Split(' ')
                           .Any( s => !double.TryParse(s, out myDouble));
```

Answer (score 2):

Split first, then parse each value. Perhaps like this:

```
string numbers = "10 20 30 40 50";
int x = 0;
var values = from str in numbers.Split(' ') 
             where int.TryParse(str, out x) 
             select x;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the first value, you can do this, too.

```
double myDouble[];
double.TryParse(textBox1.Text.Split(' ')[0], out myDouble);
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this (almost) one liner?

```
double dbl;
IEnumerable<double> doubles = 
    textBox1.Text.Split(' ')
                 .Select(str => Double.TryParse(str, out dbl) ? dbl : 0.0);
```

Gotta love one liners :)